# printWriter does not print to file

Tags: java, printwriter

I run this code but i found the output file empty.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        File outputFile=new File("out");
        PrintWriter output= new PrintWriter(outputFile);
        output.println("test");
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }

}
```

Comment: You're not closing the PrintWriter. Use try-with-resources.

Answer (score 1):

You should always remember to `close` stream.

Just add `output.close()`, then problem solved.

Of course, you'd better add it under `finally` block.